# Variable returns [object HTMLParagraphElement]

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, object

I am having difficulties working with variables in jQuery.
The var would need to return the width of the window.
To test this I wrote some code where the width is displayed in a paragraph when I hit a button:

```js
var update = function() {
  width = $(window).width();
}

$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $('button').click(
      function() {
        update,
        $('#width').text(width)
      }
    )
  }
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="width">Width</p>
<button>test</button>
```

I get "[object HTMLParagraphElement]" instead of the value of the width.
I don't understand why, because when I run this code:

```js
var width = $(window).width();

$(document).ready(
    function () {
        $('button').click(
            function () {
                $('#width').text(width)
            }
        )
    }
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="width">Width</p>
<button>test</button>
```

I do get the value without any problems. But in this way I can't update the variable after resizing the window (I think because the variable is only declared at the loading of the page.)

This probably is a real newbe problem, but I am very eager to learn...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Named' elements with `ids` are added as properties of `document`. 
This is why when you were calling `width` before, it should have been `undefined` had you not had this element

```
<p id="width">Width</p>
```

Since you had this element, `width` defaulted to `[object HTMLParagraphElement]`

See [Do DOM tree elements with ids become global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables)

Also, you need to call `update` with a `()`

```js
var update = function() {
  return $(window).width();
}

$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $('button').click(
      function() {
        var width = update();
        $('#width').text(width)
      }
    )
  }
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="width">Width</p>
<button>test</button>
```

Note, the above returns a value rather than use/assign a **global** variable `width`. This is better practice to avoid anti-patterns.

Comment: And even better, `return` a value from the function instead of assigning to an implicit global.